# Answer yes in a bash script

Tags: shell, ssh, scripting, git

I'm trying to do a `git clone` trough a bash script, but the first time that I run the script and the server is not known yet the script fails. I have something like this:

```
yes | git clone git@github.com:repo/repoo.git
```

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (207.97.227.239)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

But it's ignoring the `yes`. Do you know how to force `git clone` to add the key to the known hosts?

Comment: What about `echo yes | git clone git@github.com:repo/repoo.git`?

Comment: @asfallows, ＠Rafael: `echo yes` is not a good approach: the second time you run the command, ssh won't ask if you want to continue because the server key will already be known.

Comment: Perhaps check whether the repo you're trying to connect to has an entry in known_hosts or not (using grep) and if not then do the echo Y step.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add the following to your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host github.com
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

Anything using the open-ssh client to establish a remote shell (with the git client does) should skip the key checks to github.com.

This is actually a bad idea since any form of skipping the checks (whether you automatically hit yes or skip the check in the first place) creates room for a man in the middle security compromise. A better way would be to retrieve and validate the fingerprint and store it in the `known_hosts` file before needing to run some script that automatically connects.

Comment: With a strong preference to *retrieve and validate the fingerprint and store it in the `known_hosts` file before*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I ended up following the approach of adding the finger print in the known_hosts. It's like more secure :)

Comment: Oh I'm using puppet to do this. If someone is interested in using it here is the recipe:
https://gist.github.com/1155725

Comment: I read this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87449/how-to-disable-strict-host-key-checking-in-ssh). After modifying the `~/.ssh/config` file, `sudo chmod 400 ~/.ssh/config` is required, isnt it?

Comment: @HobinC. If you create the file from scratch, yes you need to make sure the privs on it are locked down, `chmod 400` is good. The `~./ssh` dir needs to be somewhat limited as well.

Answer (score 5):

`yes` outputs `y`.  RSA key acceptance needs `yes`.  You could try `yes yes | git clone git@github.com:repo/repoo.git` so `yes` outputs `yes` instead of `y`.

Comment: For some reason, that didn't work with git clone, for me.

Comment: Neither it worked for me. Also `echo "yes" | ...` doesn't. I think `git` doesn't accept piping. Maybe only in some version?

Answer (score 5):

Running `ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` before cloning will add the key and prevent the prompt from appearing.

Of course this approach is also vulnerable to a MITM attack.

Answer (score 3):

Run the command below (change **root** with your user):

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
```

I used this script:
with the first `IF` check if the file `/root/.ssh/known_hosts` exists, if it no exist (`else`), I create it and save the key.
If file exist check the key for github.com was added, if no add it.
Remember to change **root** with your user if you use a different.

```
if [ -f "/root/.ssh/known_hosts" ]; then
  if [ ! -n "$(grep "^github.com" /root/.ssh/known_hosts)" ]; then
    ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts 2>/dev/null;
  fi
else
  ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts 2>/dev/null;
  fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this issue before. Albeit it was on a Windows machine but we needed to use ssh to connect to a remote host. We ran into the same problem that the first connect always failed because it wouldn't recognize the keys.

I solved it by connecting manually and finding the registry key and importing it at the beginning of the script. In Linux it should be the same general idea: you want to add this server to a list of trusted hosts so that ssh won't ask you if you trust him every time.

Once you connect manually, find the key file and add it to your known_hosts file. This way ssh will look over that file, assume you know what you're doing and proceed without asking you about the fingerprint.